# angularjs download file via POST on IE8/9 without page refresh

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to download a dynamically generated file from the server using a hidden form.

Below is the angular function that I'm using to submit the hidden form

```
$scope.downloadCsv = function() {
   var dataset = JSON.stringify($scope.dataset);
   var body = $('body');
   var reportParamJson = angular.toJson($scope.dataset);
   var hiddenForm = "<form action='/Reports/SaveTestCsv' method='POST' target='_blank'><input type='hidden' name='dataset' value='" + dataset + "'/ ><button id='submitCSV' type='submit'></button></form>";
   body.append(hiddenForm);
   $('#submitCSV').click();
}
```

Below is the .net mvc method to generate the response with the file

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveTestCsv(string dataset)
{
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(dataset);
    var binary = getTestCSV(data);
    var file = File(binary, "text/csv", "test.csv");
    return file;
}
```

Below is the relevant html code from the partial html page that I'm including in the view using ng-include

```
<div><a href="#" ng-click="downloadCsv()">Download CSV</a></div>
<div ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

.

When I click on "Download CSV", Chrome, FF and IE10 prompts me to save the file without refreshing the page/view, but on IE8/9, the page is refreshed, so the content from the ng-include tag is gone, in particular the html I posted above is no longer present.

I'm wondering if this has something to do with the hashbang in the url from IE8/9 and is there any way to fix this?

### Edit

I ended up removing routing from angular completely and just use .net MVC to do the routing for me, and then it's working on IE8